# Android decodeBitmap with size depend on density

Tags: android, bitmap, decoding

I am trying to decode bitmap using only inJustDecodeBounds. But the outwidth and outheight is width the dimensions of the original image. For example if the image is in xxhdpi folder and the phone is with xhdpi density and the image is 500 x 500px then outWidth = 500, but it should be smaller, since I run it on xhdpi ( I don't have folder for xhdpi drawables). So is there a way while decoding to use screen density.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not creating a xhdpi folder and put It a smaller image ?

Comment: Because I don't want to do this. This phisical size (on xxdpi ) is excellent. It just should return me the real pixels. And it is interesting to me how to do that (decoding while using density).
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to load a scaled down version of your bitmap : 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

You can calculate reqWidth and reqHeight with values found here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Like :

```
int currentWidth = 500;
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
reqWidth = currentWidth * (metrics.densityDpi/(float)DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH );
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't a good solution, because after time maybe I will decide  to create a folder xhdpi, ot hdpi for example. I should know from which folder the picture is taken. Actually one solution is to use getDrawable() - it use the density. But there should be a wway to achieve this using Bitmap.Options class. I try inDensity and to give my density, but it doesn't work.
Thanks for your attention.
P.S. I mean it not good solution to hardcode density